# About onmouseout event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As in the follow code:

```
<div id="outerBox" style="border:1px solid red;width:300;height:300" onmouseout="alert('out')">
<div id="innerBox" style="border:1px solid blue;width:50;height:50">inner</div>
</div>
```

Why when I move mouse on the "innerBox", it was triggering `alert('out')`?

I want mouse out "outerBox" to trigger `alert('out')` only, mouse on "innerBox" don't trigger alert.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the standard behaviour for the mouseout and mouseover events.  Internet Explorer actually one-ups the competition here (for a change), because it has proprietary events that provide the behaviour that you're looking for; `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`.  The major downside is that these events aren't part of the standard and other browsers haven't implemented them.

If you use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), it has a nice cross-browser implementation with [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).  It's a good idea to use a framework to handle cross-browser events for you anyway.  It doesn't have to be jQuery, but I'm not sure if the others have a `mouseleave` event.

If you're not using jQuery or a framework that provides the simulated event, see http://ecmascript.stchur.com/2007/03/15/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-events-for-firefox-and-other-non-ie-browsers/

Comment: Prototype also has simulated `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, FWIW

Comment: @T.J. Thanks, I'll remember that.  I didn't really know which other frameworks had it.  I do know that [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html#t10) has been ranting about the events not being supported in other browsers for a while, with not much success :-)

Comment: 's head: Yeah, kind of surprising, especially given how easy it is to do it! Even Chrome doesn't have them natively.

Answer (score 2):

I found something here which looks as the function you need: http://codingrecipes.com/onmouseout-fix-on-nested-elements-javascript